# Populate a .js file with moustache js

Tags: javascript, hogan.js

I have some javascript code which requires few fields from server side. I would like to store this code in a separate `.js` file but, moustache will not be able to populate it with server side information. This is what I have:

```
<body>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/test.js"></script>
</body>
```

My .js file:

```
var testField = '{{someValue}}';
alert(testField); // is null
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use eval js function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

```
    var testTemplate = '{{someValue}}';
    var testTemplateValue = Mustache.render(testTemplate, view);
    var testField = eval(testTemplateValue);
    alert(testField);
```

Eval function is not secure, so you must take care about input manually.